# Help Identifying components in Teensy 4 schematic

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, schematics, teensy, cortex

I'm following the official schematic of Teensy 4.0 from pjrc.com to build a custom board. Can somebody please help me identify this unlabeled component encircled (Red) and this connection label encircled (blue). [Here](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/schematic40.png) is the complete schematic of Teensy 4.0. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please include the Teensy 4.0 schematic in your question - or at least include a link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the whole schematic I think

- the filled dots (you encircled in blue) are nets that go to a test points
  I think they correspond with the tiny round pads on the back side of the PCB, but I cannot confirm this by visual inspection only)
  Typically, label these nets would have been labeled on a schematic.
- the open dots (e.g the one labelled VUSB) are nets going to a connector (SMD pads or the through hole pads at the edges of the PCB)
- the 2 rectangles (you encircled in red) is a solder bridge: it is in the right upper corner: `Cut to seperate VIN from VUSB.` You can undo the cutting by applying a solder bridge again.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So I don't need to connect those filled dots to anything unless I need those test points for something. Right?

Comment: @ZeeshanDhillon Exactly

Comment: Awesome. Thank for your time.